# Tensorflow is not accepting a vector being fed to a placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

A very basic error. When feeding a vector to a placeholder, tensorflow is throwing an error even though the size is the same as the placeholder.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.constant(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))
B = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (2,1), name = 'B')
C = tf.Variable(tf.matmul(A,B), name='C')

temp = np.array([[1],[2]])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sesh:
    sesh.run(init)
    print(sesh.run(C, feed_dict = { B : temp }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't initialize a variable with a placeholder. The error is thrown by the line `sesh.run(init)`. This line tries to initialize the variable C by the value of the tensor `tf.matmul(A,B)`, but this tensor cannot be evaluated without feeding a value to B, which is not done in tf.global_variables_initializer.

If you replace

```
C = tf.Variable(tf.matmul(A,B), name='C')
```

with

```
C = tf.matmul(A,B, name='C')
```

the code works as expected.

An example of a valid initialization of a variable is:

```
v = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 1], name='v'))
```

which initializes the variable v as a matrix of random values chosen from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Oh. I see it. So here, the initialization of the variable C requires the tensor B to hold a value, but as it has not been fed yet it cannot. Thank you for your explanation.